# Why can't I have an object initializer within another object initializer in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and was wondering why I am not allowed to create another object within another.

**CODE**

```
//Object initializer
    var shoe = {
            size: 10,
            make: var maketype = {
                this.brand: "rebook"
            },
            availability: "now"
        }
```

Comment: Consider using a JavaScript validator, like http://jsHint.com . Your code simply isn't valid.

Comment: @ am not i am - I ran through my code but I would have never known from the list of errors that `var` and `this` are illegal to use in object initializers

Comment: *"Expected identifier, and instead saw 'var'"* ...seems pretty straight to the point. Anyway, validators can be very helpful.

Comment: @am not i am - It is probably I am relatively new to the world of Javascript and not understanding that `"Expected identifier, and instead saw 'var'" ` would equate to it is illegal to use. But will definitely use jshint.com in the future to test my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that very well. It's the extra `var maketype =` that is illegal (and also `this` as part of a property name).

This works:

```
var shoe = {
        size: 10,
        make: {
            brand: "rebook"
        },
        availability: "now"
    }
```

If you want to retain a separate reference to the `make`, you can do it like this:

```
var maketype = { brand: "reebok" },
    shoe = {
        size: 10,
        make: maketype,
        availability: "now"
    }
```

Comment: If I remove `var` I get the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .` at `this.brand: "rebook"`

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: `this` is also illegal in that context. Edited to clarify.

Comment: So I can't use `this` in object initializer? Does that mean that `this` is limited to constructor functions?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes and no (it's usable in all functions and also in the global context). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey—`this` is a read–only property of an execution context, it always has a value. In ECMAScript Ed 3, it always references an object, in ES5 strict mode it might be `null` or `undefined`. You can set its value by how you call a function (i.e. on entering an execution context), but can't alter it once you're in one. So in global code, `this` always references the global object.